# When you have to use "to" when using "no aida" to express "in between"

Tags: particle-と

Why are these 2 phrases different? One uses "to" between the two nouns and the other doesn't. Is the "to" optional? Is one of them incorrect?

"Hikaru sora ***to*** kumo no aida tooku habataku toritachi"

"Teeburuto doa no aida yo."

Comment: [Hikaru Sora]to [kumo]
[teburu]to[doa]
Both are between nouns.

Comment: It's all good, we all started from scratch. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences use 「と」 between nouns.

[Hikaru sora]to[kumo] 「ひかるそら」と「くも」

[Teeburu]to[doa] 「テーブル」と「ドア」

When saying "Between A and B", you need to use 「と」. However, as you may already know, usage of 「間（あいだ）」 itself does not necessarily require the use of 「と」 in other forms of use, such as 「その間」.